# Azure CLI - HTTPException('got more than 100 headers')

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-sdk-.net

I am working in a corporate environment and thus do not have a lot of visibility into the intricacies of my network settings; however, I'm still trying to troubleshoot myself.

When on a VPN, I am trying to run `az login` command for the Azure CLI.  Regardless of what configuration of arguments I use, I get an error regarding `HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443)` at the openid-configuration endpoint for my company's Azure tenant, running into the problem `(Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', HTTPException('got more than 100 headers')))`.

I have tried adding our local self-signed certs to the cacert.pem file used by the Azure CLI and adding an environment variable of `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` pointing to that path.  I have also tried setting the `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, and `ALL_PROXY` environment variables to a known endpoint for our proxy.  The error indicates python executing on a remote server; if I could update the `MAX_HEADERS` variable on that server, I would, but I believe that server is likely in MicrosoftLand somewhere and inaccessible to me.  I have tried updating the Azure CLI to the latest version.  Lastly I tried renaming the `msal_token_cache.bin` file in my APPDATA, but that has neither worked.

Please let me know if you have seen this error before and know how to overcome it.  Thank you!  This is a necessary step to use the `DefaultAzureCredential` class in C#, which is my ultimate goal.